# Do you write detailed tests as you develop, or you go back and do it later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I find that sometimes I get lost in setting up my rspec/unit tests and it takes away from actually developing the application.

Depending on the app, I find also that early on I will be doing more refactoring because I don't have my design thought out correctly and I make major changes.

Do you write detailed tests early on or is that something you add it much later as the project matures?

Answer (score 2):

**[TDD is dead. Long live testing](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/tdd-is-dead-long-live-testing.html).** - By DHH

I believe testing is essential for Application health but it should not hinder the process of Application development.

TDD is overhyped and should be avoided if you are working on a Idea.
Idea keeps changing and so is your application. I don't think TDD make sense unless you are sure about shipping the feature to production.

Personally I write tests after writing a feature and I am sure its going to merge in production. This way I am more productive.